# Set API Key required for all methods when importing API from swagger file to AWS Api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, api-key, aws-api-gateway

When creating new Rest API (or modifying existing) to AWS API Gateway by importing swagger file. How could I set Require API Key property to true for all methods? When you have tens or hundreds methods it is quite a work to set this property one by one in console.
Is there any easy way to modify swagger files so that every method contains?

```
    "security" : [ {
      "api_key" : [ ]
    } ]
```

and schema contains

```
"securitySchemes" : {
  "api_key" : {
    "type" : "apiKey",
    "name" : "x-api-key",
    "in" : "header"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have found that when creating new Rest Api by cloning existing all those settings are copied to clone. But I'd like to know how to set these common properties at first place after importing new API from Swagger file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got information that this should be made programmatically.

Here is CLI command to update Api Key required = true to one method.

aws apigateway update-method --rest-api-id xyz_123456 --resource-id xdfc452 --http-method GET --patch-operations op="replace",path="/apiKeyRequired",value="true"

I'm still looking way to update all methods at once.